# Check if all onload scripts have executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, portal

i have a situation where i want to execute a script once all onload script of the page are complete. Actually its a portal application where we have multiple onload scripts specific to multiple pages and this common script is to be called at the end of all this execution.

Is there anyway we can do it without actually making hell lot of changes in application

I have used

```
$(function(){
//todo
});

$(document).ready(function() {
//todo
});
```

Comment: are you talking about document.ready or window.onload scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery window.load method like given below

```
     $(window).load(function(){

       //Do something after all onload functions.

      });
```